# jquery ui Prevent progagation from nested Droppable inside Sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

Here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Aa7TW/

```
 {greedy: true}
```

doesn't seem to work on droppable/sortable relationship

Sortable gets fired when an item is dropped directly on it ( the outer parent layer).

When an item from the list on the right is dropped on the droppable areas (inside left "sections"), droppable gets fired twice, and then sortable gets fired again.

Is there a way to stop the propagation when an item is dragged onto droppable, and just end it there, without calling droppable for a second time, and then subsequently "sortable".

Answer (score 0):

if you want the event to stop immediately you can use. try this

```
event.stopImmediatePropagation()
```